# Context Property not correctly filled

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

When i'm getting a record of a specific table i'm not getting the expected results and i don't know why.

I have a property by the name of `Content` in the table `gbd_Content` and there i'm saving phone numbers with the format: +351 123123123

I'm then getting each record with the following expression:

```
gbd_Content record = (from c in _db.gbd_Content where c.Id == contentId && c.IsActive==true && c.IsDeleted == false select c).FirstOrDefault()
```

But the strangest thing happens, in the property `Content`i only have `123123123`

If i go to SQL Server it's properly saved with the format i want but i can't get it back correctly server side.
I'm using EF6.

[image: Debugging]

[image: sql server query]

Why is this happening?

UPDATE

It's really strange, but if i change from:

```
(from c in _db.gbd_Content where c.Id == contentId && c.IsActive==true && c.IsDeleted == false select c).FirstOrDefault()
```

to

```
_db.gbd_Content
                .Where(c => c.Id == contentId && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
```

It works...
Where do these 2 expressions differ?

Comment: are you sure the country code isn't stored in a separate column?

Comment: Pretty sure, i've confirmed in the database

Comment: debug it, check the sql that is generated by that statment or use SQL profiler to see what is executed. Take that query and run it directly against your db to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Is your Content property defined as an Integer in your class?

Comment: @Steve Ford it's defined as string. I'm going to post image of debugging and query on sql server.